# Rails - How do I display the progress of the delayed_job queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, progress-bar, delayed-job

I am new to Ruby on Rails and have a rails project that runs massive background tasks (copying several hundred files at a time for example).  Currently the job runs in the background using delayed_job, but i would like to be giving the user some indication of how long is left of the process.

My initial thought was to show the user a progress bar of some sort, but at this point i'd settle for simply displaying the countdown of tasks in the Delayed::Job.count function.  I'm assuming this wouldn't be too hard to have an AJAX view that dynamically updates based on the Delayed::Job.count function, but my question is how would i go about implementing this in my view?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could have javascript call an AJAX request every ten seconds with

```
setTimeout(f, time);
```

After the request you would set the setTimeout(f, time); function again.

If you know the delayed job ID you should be able to query the count of jobs above the ID you are processing.